# How do I handle a JSON request in Bottle?

Tags: python, json, bottle

I need to get data from JSON, transferred by Ajax from the client. Basically I used something like this:

```
@route('/ajax')
def serve_ajax():
    return main.parse_request(json.dumps(dict(request.GET)))
```

Where main.parse_request is a function, that contains some logics to deal with variables in JSON (it is a main procedure of our game engine).

So the problem is that I can't correctly handle JSON variables, by transforming `request.GET` in a dict: because in a way that I already wrote I can't pass nested objects and arrays. Also every value has a string type, while I need to have integer types on integers and string type on rest other.

Or, since I can obtain the original query string (by `request.query_string`), how can I convert a query string into an original JSON object?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Now since bottle **0.10**, the `request.json` is ready for use :)

Document is [here](https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html?highlight=json#bottle.BaseRequest.json).

Answer (score 21):

**request.json** is limited by [MEMFILE_MAX](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html?highlight=memfile#bottle.BaseRequest.MEMFILE_MAX).

Another way works if request data is larger than MEMFILE_MAX

```
json.load(request.body)
```

Comment: According to linked docs: MEMFILE_MAX is "Maximum size of memory buffer for body in bytes.". So the constraint still exists.