# Handling application/json data with bottle

Tags: json, python-3.x, bottle

I'm trying to write a simple server frontend to a python3 application, using a restful JSON-based protocol. So far, [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) seems the best suited framework for the task (it supports python3, handles method dispatching in a nice way, and easily returns JSON.) The problem is parsing the JSON in the input request.

The documentation only mention `request.fields` and `request.files`, both I assume refer to multipart/form-data data. No mention of accessing the request data directly.

Peeking at the source code, I can see a `request.body` object of type BytesIO. `json.load` refuses to act on it directly, dying in the json lib with `can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. The proper way to do it may be to first decode the bytes to unicode characters, according to whichever charset was specified in the `Content-Type` HTTP header. I don't know how to do that; I can see a StringIO class and assume it may hold a buffer of characters instead of bytes, but see no way of decoding a BytesIO to a StringIO, if this is even possible at all.

Of course, it may also be possible to read the BytesIO object into a bytestring, then decode it into a string before passing it to the JSON decoder, but if I understand correctly, that breaks the nice buffering behavior of the whole thing.

Or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: `request.json` is now around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment ([and in a similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058335/how-do-i-handle-a-json-request-in-bottle)), the `request.json` method was made available from bottle 0.1.0.

So like:

```
@route('/endpoint', method='POST')
def parse():
    body = request.json
    name = body.get('name')
    age = body.get('age')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [io.TextIOWrapper](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapper#io.TextIOWrapper) from the standard library does the trick !

```
def parse(request):
    encoding = ... #get encoding from headers
    return json.load(TextIOWrapper(request.body, encoding=encoding))
```

Comment: you've misplaced parentheses. `encoding` should be `TextIOWrapper`'s argument.

Comment: So uhm, how do you `#get encoding from headers`?

Comment: encodings = request.headers['Accept-Charset'].split(',') will give a list of potential encodings

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to read in json on a RESTful service with Python3 and Bottle:

import bson.json_util as bson_json

```
@app.post('/location/API')
def post_json_example():
    """
    param: _id, value
    return: I usually return something like {"status": "successful", "message": "discription"}
    """

    query_string = bottle.request.query.json
    query_dict = bson_json.loads(query_string)
    _id = query_dict['_id']
    value = query_dict['value']
```

### Then to Test

- from python3 interpreter, import requests
- s = request.Session()
- r = s.post('http://youserver.com:8080/location/API?json
  {"_id":"540a16663dafb492a0a7626c","value":"test"}')
- use r.text to verify what was returned.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an helper to use the good idea of b0fh.
After 2 weeks on response.json analyzing, I connect to StackOver Flow and understand that we need a work around

Here is:

```
def json_app_rqt():
    # about request
    request.accept = 'application/json, text/plain; charset=utf-8'

def json_app_resp():
    # about response
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = _allow_origin
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = _allow_methods
    # response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = _allow_headers
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

def json_app():
    json_app_rqt()
    json_app_resp()

def get_json_request(rqt):
    with TextIOWrapper(rqt.body, encoding = "UTF-8") as json_wrap:
        json_text = ''.join(json_wrap.readlines())
        json_data = json.loads(json_text)
        return json_data
```

For the using, we cand do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    json_app()

    @post("/train_control/:control")
    def do_train_control(control):
        json_app_resp()

        data = get_json_request(request)
        print(json.dumps(data))

        return data
```

Thanks to all